# Как указать определённую валюту, которая будет показана на сайте для дальнейшего парсинга

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо выводить цену предмета ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО в рублях, но код выдаёт значение всегда в разных валютах (рубли, йены, тенге, гривны, доллары, злоты и т.д.). Это идёт от особенностей самой торговой площадке стима. Как именно можно конкретизировать вывод валюты в рублях

Сам код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/MAC-10%20%7C%20Ensnared%20%28Well-Worn%29'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
name = soup.find("div", class_="market_listing_item_name_block").find("span")
cena = soup.find("span", class_="market_table_value").find("span")
print(name.text, cena.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я тут чутка накидал. Курс валюты запрашиваем только 1 раз, так как цб может ставить ограничения на кол-во запросов в сутки

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from decimal import Decimal

class SteamParser(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'https://steamcommunity.com/market/{0}'
        self.exchange_rates = ExchangeRates()
        if self.exchange_rates.json_exchange_rates is None:
            raise TypeError(self.exchange_rates)

    def is_float(self, number: str) -> bool:
        try:
            float(number)
            return True
        except TypeError:
            return False

    def parsing_page(self, page: str) -> str:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
        name = soup.find("div", class_="market_listing_item_name_block").find("span").text
        cena = soup.find("span", class_="market_table_value").find("span").text
        for i, k in self.exchange_rates.currency_icons.items():
            if k in cena:
                cena = cena.replace(k, "").replace(",", ".").strip()
                if self.is_float(cena):
                    cena = float(cena)
                    prc = "%.2f" % self.exchange_rates.calculate_the_cost(i, cena)
                    return (f"Наименование: {name}\nЦена в {k}:{cena}\nЦена в рублях: {prc}")

    def get_product_page(self, product: str) -> str:
        """
        :param product: Ссылка на товар в виде "listings/730/Dreams%20%26%20Nightmares%20Case"
        :return:
        """
        url = self.base_url.format(product)
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return self.parsing_page(response.text)


class ExchangeRates(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__url = 'https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js'
        self.json_exchange_rates = self.__get_the_exchange_rate()
        self.currency_icons = {
            "KRW": '₩',
            "EUR": '€',
            "JPY": '¥'
        }

    def __get_the_exchange_rate(self) -> json or None:
        response = requests.get(self.__url)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()

    def calculate_the_cost(self, currency_code: str, sum: float) -> Decimal:
        denomination = self.json_exchange_rates["Valute"][currency_code]["Value"]
        nominal = self.json_exchange_rates["Valute"][currency_code]["Nominal"]
        return (float(denomination) / int(nominal)) * sum

parser = SteamParser()
print(parser.get_product_page("listings/730/MAC-10%20%7C%20Ensnared%20%28Well-Worn%29"))
```